# Scheduled Task not Running on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

I go to Task Scheduler and drill down to Microsoft

[image]

Then I click on Create Basic Task and go through the wizard

[image]

At the last page of the wizard I check "Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish"

[image]

I click on "Run whether user is logged on or not"

[image]

Then I am prompted for my administrator credentials

The task never runs but it show the following after 10:15am, when it was scheduled to run

[image]

Comment: Try enabling All Task History. After that you'll be able to view the History tab.

Comment: [And the logs say...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783861%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Nixphoe --- ok now I see it ...

Comment: what does the batch file do?

Comment: @TheCleaner --- the batchfile runs a powershell script. Turns out the task was running all along. Still getting used to the bells and whistles of Windows Server 2012

Comment: So the question should be deleted?

Comment: @TheCleaner ---- I wish I can give credit to Nixphoe for being the first to answer my question. Of course, this post may help others who are also struggling with the bells and whistles of Windows Server 2012

Comment: Did you forget to run "set-executionpolicy remotesigned" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling All Task History. After that you'll be able to view the History tab.